# Control pod's container IO prioritization

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Docker offers support for some prioritization to a container's use of block device IO. It also offers control over transfer rates.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#block-io-bandwidth-blkio-constraint

I can also see it in OCI specification:

https://github.com/opencontainers/runtime-spec/blob/master/config-linux.md#block-io

How this functionality can be used with Kubernetes pods? Kubernetes offers control over CPU/Memory, but documentation lacks information on IO.
Is it possible to pass flags like --blkio-weight to docker from k8s container?
Maybe it can be achieved indirectly?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of passing `--blkio` flag into Kubernetes container.

If you would be able to build it as a representation into your `docker-compose.yml`, you can use tool called `kompose` from [kompose.io](http://kompose.io/) to convert it into Kubernetes `yaml`.

As you already mentioned the resources that can be controlled are [Compute Resources Quota](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/#compute-resource-quota).
There is also a [Storage Resource Quota](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/#storage-resource-quota), but this is for:

> You can limit the total sum of  [storage resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)  that can be requested in a given namespace.
>
> In addition, you can limit consumption of storage resources based on associated storage-class.

There is also something called [`Pod priority`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/#pod-priority), but this is for scheduling order.